# OpenCV VideoCapture.read() same frame has different values per pixel if running on different machines

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I have a C++ project running on an old windows PC, I am trying to convert it to
Python and run it on an Ubuntu machine (a Jetson Nano). I started by
simply reading a frame from a grayscale video and writing it into a text file, and I expect the result to be identical, however for some reason  it's not. specifically on the Nano, some of the pixel values
are larger than on the Windows PC.

How is this possible? can this be because of the OpenCV version, or maybe the decoder `VideoCapture.read()` is using is different (is there a way to check that)? or am I missing something in the code?

Here is the C++ code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>

std::ofstream imagetest("image_test_cpp.txt");
int main(){
    cv::Mat img;
    cv::VideoCapture m_VideoCapture;
    m_VideoCapture.open("video.avi");
    m_VideoCapture.read(img); 
    imagetest << img;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[ 12,  15,  13,  12,  15,  13,  12,  15,  13,  14, ...
  12,  15,  13,  12,  15,  13,  13,  16,  14,  15, ...
  14,  17,  15,  14,  17,  15,  13,  16,  14,  14, ...
  ... ]
```

And here is the Python code (maybe the way I write it to the file is wrong?):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image_test = open('image_test_py.txt', 'w')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.avi')

img = cap.read()
np.savetxt('image_test_py.txt', img.reshape(img.shape[0], -1),fmt="%d")
```

Output:

```
[ 12, 16, 12, 12, 16, 12, 12, 16, 12, 15, ... ]
```

(The rows in the output files didn't match so I only put the start of the first one, but I think it's enough
to see the difference)

The frame I'm reading is this:
[grayscale frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iA9rA.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What compressor was used to create the video?

Comment: Is it using the same `VideoCapture` [backend](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html) in both cases?

Comment: Perhaps one is using hardware acceleration with slightly different rounding. Video compressors aren't expected to be lossless, so it's not like one of them is wrong.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have no idea unfortunately, it was taken many years ago. Is there a way I can check?

Comment: @DanMašek is there a way I can check which backend is used?

Comment: @user253751 Okay that's good to know, Thank you very much. do you know if, for example, I am doing feature selection on the frame with ```cv.goodFeaturesToTrack()``` with different filters, that difference in pixel values can impact the result? And if yes, can I do something about it?

Comment: @NatanelBirarov [Yes](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a4576e03f447abfdbd602c0809824ec03)...